# C# - Accessing a DBF file in a Stream

Tags: c#, webmethod, dbf

I have a WebMethod which I use to allow a user to upload a database file (*.DBF). I know I can access the *.DBF file using a OleDbConnection with the appropriate connection string. But I dont really want to save the file on the server, my WebMethod has the file contents in a stream. Is there anyway I can access the *.DBF file while it is in the stream ?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to save the file on the server, at least temporarily? I'd be very surprised if you found a way of dealing with the file *just* as a stream. (You may be able to use a RAM-drive to avoid actual disk activity, of course.)

Comment: Some sort of virtual file and working in RAM - Madness!

Comment: There are lots of information about DBF files out there... IF you absolutely must access the DBF in a pure stream-manner THEN you could implement you own DBF parser... BUT I would strongly refrain from that and just save the file to disk, you can always delete it later on...