# Can I consume a downloaded dbf file without persisting it to disk first?

Tags: c#, stream, azure-webjobs, dbf, oledbconnection

I'm attempting to acquire data from a website that comes in the form of a zip folder.  Inside the zipped folder, there is a `.dbf` file that I would like to consume (moving it to an in-memory data structure that I can do things with) without persisting it to disk first.  If it is possible, I want to do this because I plan to have this code live in an Azure WebJob.

Here is what I'm working with so far:

```cs
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var data = webClient.DownloadData(url);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream))
    {
        foreach (var archiveEntry in archive.Entries.Where(entry =>
            Path.GetExtension(entry.FullName) == ".dbf"))
        {
            using (var entryStream = archiveEntry.Open())
            {
                // TODO: I know how to use an OleDbConnection to 
                // a file on disk, but I don't plan 
                // on having a filesystem to persist to...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?  Are there alternatives?

Comment: The connecting to the dbf file.  The connection string expects a file path...not a stream of bytes...

Comment: I've finally found something similar to what I'm after, and there really wasn't a conclusion made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810147/c-sharp-accessing-a-dbf-file-in-a-stream

Comment: You left out the part where you actually use the Dbf ...  Would a MemoryStream be usable? We can't tell.

Comment: That's because I don't know what to do with a stream of a dbf file. I only know what to do with it if it is persisted on disk and has a file path. In this situation exemplified above, I DON'T know how to use the dbf file. "Would a MemoryStream be usable" is just another way of asking my question I've posted

Comment: So the most relevant parts are still missing...

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you can consume the entryStream in-memory , for instance with a Hashing algorithm.

Comment: ??? Precisely! The part I don't understand how to accomplish and what I'm hoping to get help with by someone with experience in these matters is the part that is missing. I want to consume the information in the dbf file without persisting to disk first because I don't have a file system. An oledbconnection requires a file path in the connection string.

Comment: That 'oledbconnection' part was missing from the question.

Comment: That's because I assumed the answer to this did not involve the oledbconnection approach. I started mentioning the oledbconnection once additional context seemed necessary. 

How would consuming in-memory work with a hashing algorithm? I'm not familiar with the concept

Comment: [This package](https://github.com/SocialExplorer/FastDBF) seems to be able to read from a Stream.

Comment: At quick glance, it seems to only support filestream. I'll need to be more awake to try it out to confirm. But this seems to require file system persistence